# How to filter DataGrid columns on click of an external button in mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Let's say I have a datagrid table like so (from the official MUI documentation):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';

const VISIBLE_FIELDS = ['name', 'rating', 'country', 'dateCreated', 'isAdmin'];

export default function ControlledFilters() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Employee',
    visibleFields: VISIBLE_FIELDS,
    rowLength: 100,
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now let's say I wanted to filter the column 'name' in this table by onClick of a button. That button, when clicked, should give a string, let's say 'Ray'. When this button is clicked, I want to automatically filter the table so that every value in the 'name' column that contains the string 'Ray' only gets displayed.

**My Approach so far**

I have tried using `useState` from react and the `filterModel` prop in DataGrid so that pressing the button filters the table like so:

```
  ....

  const [filt, setFilt] = useState('') // Initialize it with an empty filter
  const handleClick = () => {
      setFilt('Ray');
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
        filterModel={{
          items: [{ columnField: 'name', operatorValue: 'contains', value: filt },
          ]
        }}
      />

    <Button onClick={handleClick}>Change Filter</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works but the problem with this approach is that it locks every other filter and the filter is basically stuck on the 'name' column and the user can now only use the button to filter the column. It doesn't even let me remove the filter.

I have also tried the `onFilterModelChange` prop but it didn't work; I am honestly confused on how to use it for this specific case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close.  I believe that you would need to form the entire `items` array instead of only a part of the filter object.

i.e. `setFilt([{ columnField: 'name', operatorValue: 'contains', value: "Ray"}])` instead of `setFilt("Ray")` along with `{ columnField: 'name', operatorValue: 'contains', value: filt}`

### For MUIv5

---

You can reset the filters by setting `items: []` in the `filterModel`.

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/single-grid-filter-by-button-kg7ovx) with a single filter criterion.

(I had to install `@mui/material v5.9.2` instead of `v5.9.3` to get it to work if you have any compile issues on codesandbox)

```
const [filt, setFilt] = useState([])

<DataGrid 
  {...data} 
  filterModel={{
    items: filt
  }}
/>
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    setFilt([
      {
        columnField: "name",
        operatorValue: "startsWith",
        value: "A"
      }
     ])
  }
>
  Name Starts With A
</Button>
<Button
  onClick={() => setFilt([])}
>
  Reset Filters
</Button>
```

### Bonus: Multi-filtering with buttons

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-multi-filter-with-buttons-p4g0sf?file=/demo.js) of a multi-filter grid with buttons.

Multi-filtering is only possible with the [Pro version of MUI](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#single-and-multi-filtering).  Without the Pro version, any additional filters added past the first one are ignored (as you discovered).

This is what I came up with using `@mui/x-data-grid-pro` and 3 different buttons that each apply a unique filter:

```js
const [filt, setFilt] = useState([])

<DataGridPro
  {...data}
  filterModel={{
    items: filt,
    GridLinkOperator: GridLinkOperator.And
  }}
/>
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    setFilt([
      ...filt,
      { 
         id: 1, 
         columnField: "rating", 
         operatorValue: ">", 
         value: 3 
      }
    ])
  }
>
  Rating Greater Than 3
</Button>
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    setFilt([
      ...filt,
      {
        id: 2,
        columnField: "name",
        operatorValue: "startsWith",
        value: "A"
      }
    ])
  }
>
  Name Starts With A
</Button>
<Button
  onClick={() => setFilt([])}
>
  Reset Filters
</Button>
```

A caveat to be aware of --- you will need to add an `id` to each filter object in the `items` array when using multi-filtering.

e.g.

```
[
  { id: 1, columnField: 'rating', operatorValue: '>', value: 3 },
  { id: 2, columnField: 'name', operatorValue: 'startsWith', value: "A" }
]
```

*remember this code not work in real time anymore*

### Update: Nowadays you must use `onFilterModelChange`

```
const [filt, setFilt] = useState({
    items: [{
    }]

  })

<DataGrid 
  {...data} 
  filterModel={filt}
   onFilterModelChange={(newFilterModel) =>
     setFilt(newFilterModel)
   }
/>
<Button
  onClick={() =>
    setFilt([
      {
        columnField: "name",
        operatorValue: "startsWith",
        value: "A"
      }
     ])
  }
>
  Name Starts With A
</Button>
<Button
  onClick={() => setFilt([])}
>
  Reset Filters
</Button>
```

With `onFilterModalChange` props you can update your table filter.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Additionally, I figured out another way to do it which involves relatively lesser lines of code. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Did you find a better way?  I'm curious!

Comment: Oh my bad, I completely forgot to post the answer! I'll post it right now