# Is there a way to use sortModel on multiple items?

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

Currently I have a datatable object which gets different data passed into it. I have a table with a column "Modify Date" and a separate table with a column "Start Date".

I want to be able to set both of the tables with the dates in descending order using the `initialState` prop, but MUI only allows one item.

[image]

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
    <DataGrid
      autoHeight
      pagination
      initialState={{
        sorting: {
          sortModel: [{ field: "startDate", sort: "desc" }],
        },
      }}
    />
```

But i want to add another

```
sortModel: [{ field: "startDate", sort: "desc" }],
```

or change it to

```
sortModel: [{ field: "startDate", sort: "desc" }, { field: "modifyDate", sort: "desc" }],
```

Is there a way to do something like that? or maybe have it so so the first column will always be sorted in descending order?

Comment: try `sorting: {
      sortModel: [
        { field: "startDate", sort: "desc" },
        { field: "modifyDate", sort: "desc" }
      ],
    },`

Comment: Think thats similar to an option. had? Also updated with a screenshot of the error :) and

Comment: Multi-filtering is definitely possible if you are importing the pro version of MUI.  Otherwise you are limited to one criterion.  See this answer for a detailed response on how to filter:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200492/how-to-filter-datagrid-columns-on-click-of-an-external-button-in-mui/73230178#73230178