# Programmatically Set Filters in Mui X Data Grid

Tags: javascript, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I am using MUI Data Gri (pro version).  I want to add some checkboxes to the sidebar and use those checkboxes to filter various columns.  For example, imagine I have three columns:

```
* Column Letters:  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', etc.]
* Column Numbers:  [1, 2, 3, 4,5, etc.]
* Column Names:  ['Bob', 'Bill', 'Jim', 'Joe', etc]
```

Now let's also imagine that in my sidebar, I have different checkboxes:

```
* First 10 letters of the alphabet:  []
* Last 10 letters of the alphabet: []
* Even numbers:  []
* Odd numbers: []
* Names that begin with 'B': []
* Names that begin with 'J': []
```

What I want is for someone to check one or more of those checkboxes and have them filter the appropriate columns.  What I can't figure out is how to connect the checkboxes to the Data Grid.  That is to say, I'm not having an issue with how to set up a filter to filter for only odd numbers or names that begin with B, but rather how to use a custom checkbox to apply such a filter.

I thought of using `apiRef`:  https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/api-object/

In particular, to use `setFilterModel` as noted on the Grid Api docs:  https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-api/

Now, I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but either way it is NOT working.  Here is what I tried (using a button rather than a checkbox):

```
import { useGridApiRef } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
export default function Sidebar({) {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  <DataGridPro
    apiRef={apiRef}
    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    rows={rowsData}
    columns={columnsData}
  />

  <Button
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() =>
      apiRef.current.setFilterModel([
        {
          id: 1,
          columnField: "roic10y",
          operatorValue: ">=",
          value: 10,
        },
      ])
    }
  >
    Set Filter Model
  </Button>
  );
}
```

However, when I click on this button, I get the following error:  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

[image]

Am I doing this the right way?  I.e., should I be using setFilterModel?  If so, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?  If not, what should I be doing?

Thanks :).

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200492/how-to-filter-datagrid-columns-on-click-of-an-external-button-in-mui/73230178#73230178

Answer (score 0):

Found your question while having the same problem.
Here's the typing of GridFilterItem, which `setFilterModel` expects. An object with at least a property of `items` is needed.

```
import { GridFilterItem, GridLogicOperator } from './gridFilterItem';
/**
 * Model describing the filters to apply to the grid.
 * @demos
 *   - [Pass filters to the grid](/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#pass-filters-to-the-data-grid)
 */
export interface GridFilterModel {
    /**
     * @default []
     */
    items: GridFilterItem[];
    /**
     * - `GridLogicOperator.And`: the row must pass all the filter items.
     * - `GridLogicOperator.Or`: the row must pass at least on filter item.
     * @default `GridLogicOperator.Or`
     */
    logicOperator?: GridLogicOperator;
    /**
     * values used to quick filter rows
     * @default `[]`
     */
    quickFilterValues?: any[];
    /**
     * - `GridLogicOperator.And`: the row must pass all the values.
     * - `GridLogicOperator.Or`: the row must pass at least one value.
     * @default `GridLogicOperator.And`
     */
    quickFilterLogicOperator?: GridLogicOperator;
    /**
     * If `true`, the quick filter will skip cell values from hidden columns.
     * @default false
     */
    quickFilterExcludeHiddenColumns?: boolean;
}
```

So presumably you can set it something like this:

```
onClick={() =>
 apiRef.current.setFilterModel({
  items: [
   {
    id: 1,
    columnField: "roic10y",
    operatorValue: ">=",
    value: 10,
   },
  ]
 })
}
```